# If I were to start an Android or iPhone app or game, what program should I use?

Tags: android, iphone

I don't really know a lot about programming and the only things I do is using codes with Gamemaker, but I have read that it is too basic and it can't be used with iPhone or Android.

Is there anything free that I can use to make games for those platforms? Or if not, any suggestions for engines or anything else? I was wondering about Unity, for example, is that a good investment to use for making games?

Comment: There are Gamemaker games on Android and iOS.  I'm not familiar with the process to get it on there.  There's [this page](http://wiki.yoyogames.com/index.php/Publishing_Together_with_YoYo_Games#What.E2.80.99s_happening_to_Game_Maker.3F_Surely_I.E2.80.99ll_need_a_new_version_of_Game_Maker_to_develop_games_for_iPhone_or_PSP.3F.3F) that almost addresses it.

Comment: If you own an iPad you might want to have a look at http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/

Comment: Unity might be a good option as it is tailored for game designers rather then skilled programmers. Why not check their large official tutorial http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/3d-platform-game.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation for a game engine, or for software to use (development environment)?

Comment: first of all it would be important to know which languages you can code?!

Answer (score 3):

As for the iPhone:

xCode is free for the mac, as are frameworks for making 2D games like cocos2D.

For 3D you could use a free version of unity (mac and pc) or UDK (pc), but I believe if you wanted to publish the game you'd have to pay. In fact if you want to publish anything anywhere you pretty much have to pay a little bit for a licence, but the making and learning part can be free.

If you're not really a programmer I would recommend either UDK or unity (unity is a bit more simple and iPhone friendly at this point). You don't need to code with them, but are things you can script if you want to get into that side of things.

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/iphone-publishing) (Recommended for beginners)

[UDK](http://www.udk.com/mobile)

Answer (score 1):

If you know Python, you can use [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) to develop apps for both iOS and Andriod. Kivy is free, can be used on Windows, Linux, and OS X. The Kivy site has got tons of documentation and resources. The only problem with it is that there aren't many examples of source code out there (though they provide a few starter tutorials).

As for learning Python, it's a pretty language easy to learn. May I suggest [this site](http://inventwithpython.com/) to get started with game programming in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a hudge fan of libgdx, it's not an engine, but I think that is for the better. A  summary can be found on there [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GoalsFeatures).